Are confidentiality agreements in internal reports lifetime?
I gave a talk in the most valued French conference of my field (Operations Research) during the first year of my MSc in 2018. I kept working hard, dedicating my life to research during the final year at a French CAC40 company Research and Development lab and signed for the following confidentiality note within my internal report:

This memoir is confidential. Therefore, any difusion of its content outside the Master
Parisien de Recherche Opérationnelle’s professorship or the DASSAULT SYSTEMES’
personnel is strictly forbidden. All information in this document is the exclusive
intellectual property of DASSAULT SYSTEMES. Any receiver of this document cannot
communicate its content without written authorization of DASSAULT SYSTEMES.
ENHANCED PRIVACY
DASSAULT SYSTEMES CONFIDENTIAL 2019
ANY REPLICATION, MODIFICATION OR PUBLICATION IS STRICTLY FORBIDDEN
THIS REPORT MUST BE RETURNED TO THE COMPANY AFTER EVALUATION BY THE
JURY

At that moment of my scholarity, I had no idea how valuable my internal report was. I graduated from my MSc with honours, pursued in this very field during my thesis and I am still dedicating myself for operations research and to publish during my post-doc with the aim to be an assistant professor, hopefully.
Will I be allowed to publish my 2019 MSc memoir online at some point? Is the confidential note from 2019 expirable? We are more than 5 years later, I guess my ex-company published those results on international journals now, though I did not search it. Another side question: is it important to search the litterature for it?

If the results were published any confidentiality agreement would be mute, don't you think? Would you not expect to be included as a co-author?

You should ask the company or a lawyer about this. However, I kind of doubt there will be any timely expiry unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Both comments should be combined into an answer.

What do you mean by a "memoir"? And, whose lifetime, exactly?

It seems if there is no time limit in the notice then it would depend on whether perpetual contracts are acceptable legally in your jurisdiction. This seems like lawyer territory.

I think "memoir" is a poorly translated French word, perhaps adjacent to "memo". I take it that it is an internal report within the company.

Time does not turn proprietary information into non-proprietary automatically. You need to communicate with them, preferably with any manager you worked with.

@WolfgangBangerth, thank you for the correct vocabulary :) I still have a lot to learn in English Language <3

@BryanKrause, you wrote that this seems like lawyer territory while in my mind, this is about sharing knowledge to the scientific world

@JonCuster, I agree, no date was written, I will find a way to contact Dassault

@JKHA Whatever your goals are, the question you ask is about law. Sometimes law cares what your goal is, sometimes it does not.

The simple solution is to not make assumptions, but to ask the company for permission to publish and end the agreement. If they are hesitant, ask them for a future date on which they would agree that it is ok to publish. Their reasons for wanting confidentially may well have become obsolete.
But you seem to have agreed to give up all IP rights. In essence you are asking for them back. Since they are literally the owners, it is up to them to agree, or not. If the work is so important to them that they consider it a trade secret then you won't get permission.
If they have published the results already, then there are issues of plagiarism on their part if you aren't listed as author, but I doubt (contrary to a comment) that it constitutes release from a signed agreement.
You might be able to list the work generically in a CV, however, without details, noting that the work was done confidentially with control by the corporation.
You might also be able to point to their publication of the work if it has happened, but even claiming that it is yours, without their agreement, has legal implications given your agreement. They might agree to let you do that, at least if you ask. But, yes, you need to search to see what the current situation is.

This summarize the whole situation quite well. Thank you Buffy :)
